# How to set value inside ' '

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have some snippet of code

```
 for(var i=0; i < this.arr.length; i++) {
      arr.push({
          id: 'i',
          label: this.arr[i],
          display: () => this.arr[i]
      })
  }
```

I wonder how to set value inside ' ' for each iteration. I want something like that '1' , '2' , '3' .....

Comment: `arr.push({
          id: i.toString(),
          label: this.arr[i],
          display: () => this.arr[i]
      })`

Comment: use `i.toString()`

Comment: If you want to add prefix or suffix then you can use template literals, `id: \`prefix ${id} suffix\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplist way ist to use the `.toString()` method.

```
for(var i=0; i < this.arr.length; i++) {
  arr.push({
      id: i.toString(),
      label: this.arr[i],
      display: () => this.arr[i]
  })
}
```

### Example

```js
let arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < [1, 2, 3, 4].length; i++) {
  arr.push({
    id: i.toString()
  })
}
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're saying you want quoted numbers, do this:

```js
var arr = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
var res = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  res.push({
    id: `'${i}'`,
    label: arr[i],
    display: () => arr[i]
  })
}

console.log(res);
```

This uses template literals to inject `i` into the resulting string between the single quotes.

Note that your `display` function in each object will give an unexpected value for `arr[i]`. To fix this, declare `i` with `let` instead of `var`.

Answer (score 1):

This code set in id the string '0', '1', '2' ...

```
for(var i=0; i < this.arr.length; i++) {
      arr.push({
          id: '\''+i.toString()+'\'',
          label: this.arr[i],
          display: () => this.arr[i]
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace -   id: 'i',  to   id: " ' "+i+" ' ",

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you need to convert your `i` which is type `number` to type `string`

So instead of:

```
id: 'i',
```

You can do:

```
id: i.toString(),
```

or

```
id: ''+i,
```

or

```
id: `${i}`,
```